# Django POST with ModelViewSet and ModelSerializer 405

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

How can I make a ModelViewSet accept the POST method to create an object? When I attempt to call the endpoint I get a 405 `'Method "POST" not allowed.'`.

Within views.py:

```
class AccountViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    """An Account ModelViewSet."""

    model = Account
    serializer_class = AccountSerializer
    queryset = Account.objects.all().order_by('name')
```

Within serializers.py:

```
class AccountSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    name = serializers.CharField(required=False)
    active_until = serializers.DateTimeField()

    class Meta:
        model = Account
        fields = [
            'name',
            'active_until',
        ]

    def create(self, validated_data):
        with transaction.atomic():
            Account.objects.create(**validated_data)
```

within urls.py:

```
from rest_framework import routers

router = routers.SimpleRouter()
router.register(
    prefix=r'v1/auth/accounts',
    viewset=AccountViewSet,
    base_name='accounts',
)
```

Do I need to create a specific `@action`? my attempts to do so have yet to be successful. If that is the case what would the `url = reverse('app:accounts-<NAME>')` be such that I can call it from tests? I haven't found a full example (urls.py, views.py, serializers.py, and tests etc).

Comment: Which endpoint are you using?

Comment: I am following the pattern listed [here](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/routers/) and using `reverse('appname:accounts-list')` -> `/v1/auth/accounts/`

Answer (score 1):

I discovered what the issue was, I had a conflicting route. There was a higher level endpoint registered before the AccountViewSet.

```
router.register(
    prefix=r'v1/auth',
    viewset=UserViewSet,
    base_name='users',
)

router.register(
    prefix=r'v1/auth/accounts',
    viewset=AccountViewSet,
    base_name='accounts',
)
```

[Django runs through each URL pattern, in order, and stops at the first one that matches the requested URL.](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/urls/#how-django-processes-a-request). I should have been ordered this way:

```
router.register(
    prefix=r'v1/auth/accounts',
    viewset=AccountViewSet,
    base_name='accounts',
)

router.register(
    prefix=r'v1/auth',
    viewset=UserViewSet,
    base_name='users',
)
```

despite the fact that `reverse('appname:acccounts-list')` worked, the underlying URL router still thought I was calling the UserViewSet.

Answer (score 0):

From the docs:

A ViewSet class is simply a type of class-based View, that does not provide any method handlers such as .get() or .post(), and instead provides actions such as .list() and .create().

And here is a list of supported actions:

```
def list(self, request):
    pass

def create(self, request):
    pass

def retrieve(self, request, pk=None):
    pass

def update(self, request, pk=None):
    pass

def partial_update(self, request, pk=None):
    pass

def destroy(self, request, pk=None):
    pass
```

So no post is not directly supported but create is. 
So your end point would be v1/auth/accounts/create when using the a router instead v1/auth/accounts/post.

I honestly prefer using class based or function based views when working with DRF. It resembles regular django views more closely and makes more sense to me when working with them. You woul write you views and urls pretty much like regular django urls and views.